# Scope private classes in a separate file

Tags: javascript, oop

Is there a way to create a private class in a separate file without polluting the global namespace? Currently I just create a sub-namespace and put all of the private classes that other public classes need to function, but is there a way to just make a class altogether private, yet in another file?

Comment: You can use a loader such as [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) or [commonjs](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS).

Comment: Ah, so that's what that's for. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look into the "Module Pattern" in JavaScript.  There are a lot of flavors, but I expect one of them is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the "Module Pattern" in JavaScript.  The Module Pattern name can refer to a lot of different patterns but the basic concept to to declare functions and attributes that are only available to a function which has already been called.  Like this:

```
 myModule = function () {
    var me = {},
        iAmPrivate = 1;

     function privateFunc() {
        // stuff can access iAmPrivate and iamPublic
     }

     me.iamPublic = 1;
     me.publicFunc = function () {
        // stuff can access iAmPrivate and iamPublic
     };

     return me;

 }());

 myModule.publicFunc();  // this can be called
 myModule.iamPublic;     // this can be accessed

 myModule.iAmPrivate     // xx can't do this
 myModule.privateFunc()  // or this
```

Because of how closures and scope works, Items declared local to that function call are available to all functions declared in that function call but nothing outside of the function call.  The function has been called so they can never be accessed.

You can read a lot more about it here : http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html, and of course with a Google search now that you know what it is called.

Comment: I guess my original question though was: what happens if you want to define a private method/class in a file separate from the calling module? Is that possible?

Comment: @sircodesalot - Not sure what exactly you are asking.  Take the code above and put it in a file called hogan_wrote_this.js  Then in another file if you want to use it just load it. This is how every JavaScript framework or library works.

Comment: What I mean is that the private members are implemented as part of the closure. If I wanted to say, create another class (and make it private - only accessible to other members of the containing closure), then I would put that class into the closure along with it's consumers. What would be nicer though, is to have that class defined, but in a separate file...while still ensuring that said class remains private. If you capture it in a module, then it's no really longer private because the module is technically globally accessible.

Comment: @sircodesalot - No it is private.  All code defined in the closure can't be accessed by other code even if the module (the myModule in the example above) is available to other code.  The module pattern works and is good, however how modules in JavaScript will work in the future is formalized in JavaScript 6 (sometimes called Harmony) specification. JavaScript 6 modules are implemented in node.js for example and most modern browsers.  They work exactly the same as the module pattern described above with some slight syntax sugar.

Comment: Okay, but the question is, if you need a closure to make an item private, can a closure span multiple files?

Comment: @sircodesalot - This question does not really make any sense.  In JavaScript (5 or 6) you can put stuff in different files but at some point you "reference" the other files which logically loads the code at that point as if the interpreter was reading from just one location. THE CODE IS IN DIFFERENT FILES AND WORKS FINE.  This is clear as soon as you start using JavaScript.  Have you even tried any of this?  It seems you are demanding answers and not happy to hear "yes".  Please try some of this out and stop asking the same question over and over.  Time to codealot and not questionalot

Comment: `This question does not really make any sense`. That is the answer to the original question. You can't span a closure over multiple files. Obviously you can make an item private within a single closure (module), but because you cannot make closures span multiple files it's impossible to make one private item access another in the same scope, yet across files. Thanks!

Comment: @sircodesalot - I see what you mean now, there are ways to do this - take a look at how jQuery implements modules.  Basically you need to build in the ability to "hook" to the hidden items into the base class.  jQuery is probably the simplest mature example.